# Build only scss files to css prevent compiling/building the JS or build only js while preventing compiling scss using webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, sass-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

So I am trying to create only css files or only js files at a time from the index.js file, which import few react component.

```
.
├── index.js
    ├── Header
        ├── index.js
        └── styles.scss
    └── Body
        ├── index.js
        └── styles.scss
    └── Footer
        ├── index.js
        └── styles.scss
    ├── Common
        └── Button
            ├── index.js
            └── styles.scss
        └── Label
            ├── index.js
            └── styles.scss
```

Now how do I create two different task `npm run build:js` and `npm run build:scss` to get js and css differently?
Sometimes I just need to change the styles, but I had to a build for js as well. To prevent that I am trying this out.

EDIT1 - There's one more thing I forgot to add,
All these `Header, Body, Footer` components imports different molecule level components like `Button, Label`. At the end the outcome expected is

```
.
 ├── Header.js
 ├── Header.scss
 ├── Body.js
 ├── Body.scss
 ├── Footer.js
 └── Footer.scss
```

Comment: that is not a proper task for webpack. You better run a task runner(gulp) instead.

Comment: Why not just use the `sass` CLI to build your SCSS outside of Webpack?

Comment: Thanks a ton
@PlayMa256 Well, I was thinking about a task runner but @adam got a good point, running build using sass as I dont wanna introduce new task runner. ( Though I am open to any, if it solves the task).
But @adam, how would you add the entry point to ```index.js``` to sass cli?